# How to change the GitHub ZIP releases folder names?

Tags: github

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

My GitHub username (example only): abcdef123456

My project name & private repository: ghijkl789012

My new release: 0.1

The releases URL: https://github.com/abcdef123456/ghijkl789012/releases/tag/0.1

The ZIP file URL: https://github.com/abcdef123456/ghijkl789012/archive/refs/tags/0.1.zip

The ZIP file: ghijkl789012-0.1.zip

The main folder name in ZIP: ghijkl789012-0.1

The ZIP file name is okay (ghijkl789012-0.1.zip), but how to change the folder name in ZIP with automatically when I create a new releases in GitHub? I would like folder name in ZIP: ghijkl789012 (not need the -0.1 version number in ends).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub doesn't provide an option to change the folder names.

If you need a different folder name, you can clone the repository and generate one with your desired folder name with `git archive` and the `--prefix` option.  Note that you will want to end the prefix with a slash to create a directory.

If you have an automated CI system, you can do the above using your CI system and add your own release asset to the release using the API to upload release assets.